# Software for deleting files used by another process

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-unlocking

I want a software, similar to Unlocker or something in which we can delete files that are used by another process, for Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: [Warning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx?pr=blog), you could be headed for data corruption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the Kernel itself, you may be out of luck... If you mean just on Windows 2008 R2, I recommend you use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

You can press the find button and type the name of the file you are trying to delete, it will then show you what application / module has an active handle to it and basically kill that process so you can delete the file.

Comment: i dont want to kill the process as i know which process is using that file. I just want to unlock that file from that process.

Comment: You can close the handle, not need to kill the process. Some applications might not like it, some will not bother. And instead of killing the app, just closing it gracefully will do too :-) .

Answer (score 2):

The sysinternals [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) command can find what process has a file locked, and forceably close the handle.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [Lockhunter](http://lockhunter.com/?ver=&vertype=pro&sm=main_window_64).

Answer (score 0):

Try [WhoLockMe](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/). It says NT/2K/XP but it may work with 2008

Answer (score -1):

To delete files / folder locked by the system.
1.- Locate the folder c:\users\xxx
2.- Try to take ownership of the folder and subfolder : (it will probably failed)
3.- If not failing, give you full rights to the folders and subfolder and delete it.
4.- But since it’s failing, we need to find witch windows process lock the files.
5.- Start Microsoft SysInternal\procexp.exe
6.- Go to find, find handle
7.- Do a search c:\users\xxx
8.- Take not of the PID number that is locking the files (second column)
9.- Go back and Kill process or Kill process tree if it’s a tree.
10.- Go back to the folder and take the owner ship of the folder and subfolder c:\users\xxxx
11.- Give you full rights of the folder and subfolder c:\users\xxx
12.- Delete the c:\users\xxx folder
13.- Log back the user, he will have a fresh new profiles.

How to take owner ship and give you full rights of a folders and subfolders
1.- Locate your c:\users\xxx folder
2.- Right mouse on it | properties | Security | Advanced | Owner | Edit | Choose your ad account | Replace Owner on subcontainers and objects | Apply
3.- Go back to Permissions tab | change permissions | add your ad account | Full control | Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object
4.- Now delete your c:\users\xxx folder.

Comment: This is not what he asked, he asked practically an Unlocker alternative.